# Lookup table: matching two pairs of data

Tags: r, lookup-tables

Data test:

```
T   RH
1  10
2  10
3  12
4  11
5  14
```

Look up Table:

```
T   RH   Rate
1  10     5
2  11     4
3  12     3
4  13     2
5  14     1
```

Output desired:

```
T   RH  Rate
1  10    5
2  10    NA
3  12    3
4  11    NA
5  14    1
```

NA because not matched with Lookup Table

What type of R-code cope with my problem? Thanks

Comment: What you want is a left join. `dplyr::left_join(testdata, lookup)` or base R: `merge(testdata, loopup, all.x=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks 
But the sequence of data and output changes, how to keep it the same?

Comment: What exactly do you mean that the sequence changes? When I try with the test data the order stays the same. Is your input data.frames or data.tables? Can you not just sort to get the order you want afterward?

Comment: Oke 
Using this: dplyr::left_join(testdata, lookup)
The sequence of data and ouput is the same
Many thanks

Comment: Oke 
Using this: dplyr::left_join(testdata, lookup)
The sequence of data and ouput is the same
Many thanks